# Some good resources on viruses/worms?

Tags: professional-education, research, virus

I am searching good info on sophisticated viruses/worms. One example would be STUXNET and the very good [analysis](http://www.symantec.com/content/en/us/enterprise/media/security_response/whitepapers/w32_stuxnet_dossier.pdf) made by folks from Symantec. Any ideas?

Comment: I just did a presentation on Stuxnet actually.  Do you only want info on Stuxnet, if not what other worms?  Also, do you want technical info or more news-type articles?  I have several from each.

Comment: I would like to see others as well, and I am rather interested in technical details (mostly replication strategies)

Answer (score 4):

Celebrity malware like Stuxnet, Confiker, Zeus will get the kind of attention you're referring to. Any list of those sort of reports is going to get out of date very fast though.

Many organisations inlcuding [Symantec](http://www.symantec.com/business/security_response/whitepapers.jsp), [Trusteer](http://www.trusteer.com/research/publications), Microsoft, [SRI](http://mtc.sri.com/pubs/) and Sophos publish malware analysis reports. There aren't any RSS feeds of these resources and some organisations spread the content all over their web presence in blogs, press releases and the like (Microsoft is particularly bad at this). You'll also have to wade through some promotional content from the commercial vendors and other research output from the pure research outfits. The easiest way to keep up with most of the publications in this area is to follow the [SANS Internet Storm Center](http://isc.sans.edu) who publish links to a lot of the papers.

Shallower but more immediate analysis can be found from the [VirusTotal community](http://www.virustotal.com/community.html) or [ThreatExpert](http://www.threatexpert.com/).

Answer (score 1):

There is an extensive new analysis of Stuxnet by Kim Zetter at Wired: [How Digital Detectives Deciphered Stuxnet, the Most Menacing Malware in History | Threat Level | Wired.com](http://www.wired.com/threatlevel/2011/07/how-digital-detectives-deciphered-stuxnet/)

Comment: more like a novel than an analysis :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for real technical info and not just executive summaries, here's a blog you will enjoy

http://contagiodump.blogspot.com/ and the sister site http://contagiominidump.blogspot.com/

~~~

Edit: Just wanted to add another one, probably one of the best of its kind:

http://www.malwareblacklist.com/showMDL.php

warning: these sites contain links to real malware samples